# org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: aem, osgi-bundle

The following exception is throwing on my cq pages, when I have the following code in a service class inside osgi bundle.  **Any ideas ??**

> org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

**service.getFund() will be called from JSP using Sling.getService() api**

```
@Component
@Service(ProductService.class)
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    public Fund getFund() {

        Product[] origList = resultProducts();  
        Product dumP = copyCustom(origList[0]);
        List<Product> pp = new ArrayList<Product>();
        pp.addAll(new ArrayList<Product>(Arrays.asList(origList)));
        pp.add(dumP);
        filteredProducts = (Product[])pp.toArray();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T> T copyCustom(T entity) throws IllegalAccessException,  InstantiationException {

        Class<?> clazz = entity.getClass();
        T newEntity = (T) entity.getClass().newInstance();

        while (clazz != null) {
            copyFields(entity, newEntity, clazz);
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        }
        return newEntity;
    }

    private <T> T copyFields(T entity, T newEntity, Class<?> clazz) throws   IllegalAccessException {
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            fields.add(field);
        }

        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(newEntity, field.get(entity));
        }

      return newEntity;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info - Complete Stacktrace, how you are using the class and where is that class being called from? Is it a slingModel or normal java class? Are you calling it in a jsp, sightly ?

Comment: your osgi bundle might not be exporting this service so its not available in jsp.